# How to combine route name with route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I need to pass Name = XXX to a method that already contains a {YY} parameter.

So I am trying to combine

```
    [HttpPut(Name = "SomeFunc")]
    public bool SomeFunc()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
    [HttpPut("{abc}")]
    public bool SomeFunc(string abc)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

So that I have something like this

```
    [HttpPut(Name = "SomeFunc")("{abc}")]
    public bool SomeFunc(string abc)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

But I can't quite find the correct syntax to do so. How do you combine parameters like this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Route `{abc}` and name `SomeFunc`? If so, `[HttpPut("{abc}", Name = "SomeFunc")]`

Comment: Thank you ... [HttpPut("{abc}", Name = "SomeFunc")] was what I was looking for. Somehow I could have sworn I tried that ... but apparently not. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking.
Is this what you want?

```
[HttpPut("{abc}", Name = "SomeFunc")]
public bool SomeFunc(string abc)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to have a route named `SomeFunc` that has a route parameter `abc`, if that's the case, then you should use:

```
[HttpPut("{abc}", Name = "SomeFunc")]
public bool SomeFunc(string abc)
{
    return true;
}
```

Notice that the route is a constructor parameter (parameter order matters) while the name is an optional, named parameter (parameter order doesn't matter).

Comment: Same response as JOSEFtw -> the additional note is additional value, though. Thank you!

Comment: @Aidanapword Considering that I commented with this solution almost 10 minutes before JOSEFtw answered, I don't know the point of your comment :) I just wasn't sure if this was what the OP wanted, so I waited for their response before posting an answer